# In Python, how do I match and substitute anything before or after a specific character?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to understand matching patterns before or after a specific character.

I have a string:

```
myString = "A string with a - and another -."
```

**QUESTION:** What regular expression should be used in the following substitution function that allows me to match anything *after* the first '-' character such that the following function would print everything before it?

```
print re.sub(r'TBD', '', myString) # would yield "A string with a "
```

**QUESTION** How would it change if I wanted to match everything before the first '-' character?

```
print re.sub(r'TBD', '', myString) # would yield " and another -."
```

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following solution for `re.sub`:

```
import re

myString = "A string with a - and another -."
print(re.sub(r'-.*',r'',myString))
#A string with a 
print(re.sub(r'^[^-]+-',r'',myString))
# and another -.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`re.search`** with lookahead and lookbehind to match the first occurance:

```
import re

myString = "A string with a - and another -."

print(re.search(r'.*?(?=-)', myString).group())  # A string with a

print(re.search(r'(?<=-).*', myString).group())  # and another -.
```

---

There is a better way if you are sure a `regex` is not mandatory:

```
myString = "A string with a - and another -."

splitted = myString.split('-')

print(splitted[0])            # A string with a
print('-'.join(splitted[1:])) # and another -.
```

Answer (score 0):

re.search will get you an answer, and you can edit it by converting it to list and rejoin it.

```
import re

m = re.compile(r'(.*?)[-]')
p = m.search('A string with a - and another -.')
print(''.join(list(p.group())[:-1]))

n = re.compile(r'-(.*?)-')
q = n.search('A string with a - and another -.')
print(''.join(list(q.group())[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.partition()` works on the first occurrence, you could use this to partition your string then you would have a list with everything before and after in separate indexes.

```
my_string = "A string with a - and another -."
s = my_string.partition('-')
print(s[0]) # A string with a 
print(s[-1]) # and another -.
```